# Highcharts - Invalid Argument in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, highcharts, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting an error of Invalid Argument in IE8, and in IE11 the chart is setting its own width to 2px instead of filling its containing div.

I couldn't find any trailing comma's or anything else weird with the code.

Here is the part of script causing the issue:

```
$('#PieApproverDivision').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'iAcquire Expense Status: Primary Approver'
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td><td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:,.0f}</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#C5BABA',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {   
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%<br/>${point.y:,.0f}</b>'                        
                }                    
            }
        },          
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: "AUD",
            //colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{

                        name: "Remaining Allocation",

                            y: 0.0001

                            ,dashStyle: 'dash'
                            ,color: 'rgba(234,231,231,1)'

                            },{

                        name: "xyz  ",

                            y: 12345 
                            },{

                        name: "abc   ",

                            y: 7010 
                            },{

                        name: "def  ",

                            y: 799516 
            }]
        }]
    });
```

Note* I'm using Jquery 1.9.1 and Highcharts 3.0.10

Comment: What happens with example codes from highchart? Do they work?

Comment: The samples on the Highcharts website work fine. And I have another few graphs on this page that work perfectly, even one with the exact same setup as this - which is why this issue was particularly perplexing. :(

Comment: I dont see any errors in the code you provided. Must be some kind of bug. I suppose you should copy the working chart and change it step by step to what you need, to see at what point it breaks. Good luck

Comment: Could you recreate your example as live demo (on jsfiddle.net)  to introduce issue? Because your code looks like properly and works well.